# mintty support for sixel graphics?

Tags: terminal, xterm, mintty

I have [mintty](https://mintty.github.io/) 3.06 installed, running Ubuntu 18.04 with WSL1.

This should support [sixel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sixel) graphics [as far as I know,](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/img2sixel.1.html) but no graphics have worked.

I try:

```
img2sixel png|jpeg
 w3m -o ext_image_viewer=0 png|jpeg
```

And I just get blankness.

I have tried changing font sizes, changing terminal modes (vt340, xterm-256), and googling.

Comment: WSL1 is extremely limited; WSL2 a little less limited. Also, mintty is not an Ubuntu app, but a Cygwin app. Click on the link in the first sentence of your question for mintty information.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work!

I upgraded to the latest mintty (3.1.4.2, installed from wsltty package). So consider it a bug in that version of mintty.

Now img2sixel just works. w3m does not, but I will figure that out later.